# How could I make the image view, that is located in too bar, response user actions

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uitoolbar, sdwebimage

I've added an image view, that is loaded by SDWebImage, to a tool bar.

```
...
[imgv setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];
 UIBarButtonItem *userpicture = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imgv];
```

I want image view to response to user tap action. But I read from below link that it's not possible to apply setTarget and setAction methods to custom image views.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2796488/1320039

How could I make the image view, that is located in tool bar, response user actions.

Comment: Did you try to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to your image view than handle tap event ?

Comment: Thanks Musti. UITapGestureRecognizer  worked.

Comment: Added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained the question you linked, `setTarget` and `setAction` methods don't work as they're supposed to. But, what you can do is to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your imageview and you'll be able to handle tap event.