# Where I create the method from action:@selector from a UIToolBar in a PickerView with a delegate different then self?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerviewcontroller

I create a Cocoa Touch Class, called MyPLayer

MyPLayer.h

```
@interface MyPLayer : NSObject<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

and inside there I create a picker view.

MyPlayer.m

```
@implementation MyPLayer
SINGLETON_GCD(MyPLayer);
```

In the method to start the video capture:

```
+ (void)startCaptureVideoFromViewController:(UIViewController *)controller videoUploadProgressionHandler:(VideoUploadProgressionBlock)videoUploadProgressionBlock videoSavedHandler:(VideoSavedBlock)videoSavedBlock videoCanceledHandler:(VideoWasCanceledBlock)videoCanceledBlock captureFailedHandler:(FailDetailsBlock)failBlock {

id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> delegate = [MyPlayer sharedInstance];
```

And in the UIPickerViewController inside my library I set the delegate

```
picker.delegate = delegate;
```

After define the picker.mediaTypes and picker.cameraDevice, I create a UIToolbar, and inside I create a button.

```
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [dadosUsuario doubleForKey:@"toolBarHeigh"]-54, [dadosUsuario doubleForKey:@"toolBarWidth"], 55)];

toolBar.barStyle =  UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera  target:self action:@selector(shootVideo)],
       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
                nil];
[toolBar setItems:items];
```

On my UIViewController I call my MyPlayer, call the method the show the UIPickerView. The overlay appears, also the button. But where can I create the method to match the @selector on the UIToolbar?

All the UIPicker Delegate methods are inside MyPLayer, but I can't fire the UIBarItem. I think this is because the delegate or something else.

When I declare all this code (picker view , uibaritem and selector method)in a regular UIViewController, this works fine.

Comment: this is incomprehensible and not related to Xcode by any means.

Comment: I tag Xcode because is related with Apple iOs Dev

Comment: I guessed, but it doesn't matter – you should tag with "iOS" or "cocoa-touch" then since your question does not relate to the IDE being used. You can develop for iOS using any IDE (heck, I use Emacs!). Your question has to do with the Cocoa Touch API.

Comment: re-taged ! It's hard to find the answer, because basic I just have to declare the method to match the action. But I already try all the combinations possibile on target  / action but the method was not hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this post

[UIBarButtonItem: target-action not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796438/uibarbuttonitem-target-action-not-working)

The only way that I found to work was create a UIButton, instead of a UIToolbar / UIBarButtonItem.