# Add target for UIBarButtonItem with Custom View not Working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

### Hello there,

I have a problem with adding a custom action to a UIBarButtonItem
The Target does not called 
Did someone see the problem?

```
    let navBarMapImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22))
    navBarMapImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navBarMapImageView.image = image
    navBarMapImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    navBarMapImageView.target(forAction: #selector(openMaps), withSender: self)
    let navBarMapButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navBarMapImageView)
```

#### thanks for help

Comment: Why are you using UIImageView, Instead use UIButton.

Comment: yes, good question, I do not no why
with the button is definitely the better way :-D

Comment: Because UIImageView is not a control, you can't add a target for control events to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are adding target to `UIImageView`, it's not work please check below code

```
    let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
    btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openMaps), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to add a different approach.

You can create some custom bar item class and write your specific initializer for customView. For example;

```
fileprivate class BarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

    @objc func buttonAction()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(customView: UIControl) {
        self.init()
        self.customView = customView
        customView.addTarget(self, action: .onBarButtonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
    }

fileprivate extension Selector {
    static let onBarButtonAction = #selector(BarButtonItem.buttonAction)
}
```

And with this way, you can even add closure inside your buttonAction.

```
var actionCallback: ( () -> Void )?
    @objc func buttonAction() {
        actionCallback?()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use a UIButton and assign it as bar button item as suggested in this thread:

[UIBarButtonItem: target-action not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796438/uibarbuttonitem-target-action-not-working)

```
    let button  = UIButton(type: .custom)
    if let image = UIImage(named:"icon-menu.png") {
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }

    button.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.myMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the target to `navBarMapButton` and not to the `navBarMapImageView`.