# Custom navigation bar button and action to open a new viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I´m trying to make a new custom navigation bar button with my own image. That´s working fine, but I´m trying to open a new view controller when I press that button. Unfortunately that doesn´t work and I have no idea how I should do it.

```
let testUIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Image.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = testUIBarButtonItem
func clickButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem){}
```

That´s my code right now and its inside my viewDidLoad. My intention is to perform a show detail Segue comment.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `Storyboard`, add a manual `segue` to your `ViewController` and give it an identifier. Then you have to call `performSegue` in your custom navigationbar button's `IBAction`.

```
func clickButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: I´ve made a manual segue but it still won´t open the new view controller

`let testUIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Image.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = testUIBarButtonItem
        
        func clickButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "idPage3", sender: nil)}`

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is you IBAction even called?

Comment: I don´t get any errors and I really think that my action isn´t being called. Nothing happens wen I push that button. Do I have forgotten something ? Is it correct to have all in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: As I mentioned, have a look in this thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796438/uibarbuttonitem-target-action-not-working

Try my example code from my answer above and assign the selector with your click button function. It will work. And yes, it is legit to have all this configuration set up in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now. I had forgotten this paragraph in my code `action:#selector(Class.MethodName)` and all worked after I´ve moved my `fun clickButton`below my `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use a UIButton and assign it as bar button item as suggested in this thread:

[UIBarButtonItem: target-action not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796438/uibarbuttonitem-target-action-not-working)

```
let button  = UIButton(type: .Custom)
if let image = UIImage(named:"icon-menu.png") {
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
}
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.myMethod), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```